# Delete showing 1 of N entries using R

Tags: javascript, r, datatable, shiny

I'm stucked in a problem deleting the bottom information of a datable, I have just find a JS script that make it doable, but I dont know how to apply it to my R code in Shiny.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#Example').dataTable({
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": true,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bAutoWidth": false 
  });
});
```

Comment: It is unclear to me what your problem is. Please create a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and show us exactly what your issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not so clear and I am not expert in javascript. Based on whatever I understand I am writing this answer:

let say you have dataset `df`
Now, If you want to remove it as per the example then create a matrix of those example with equal `columns` then use `set` operation .
One example code is like below:

```
df <- iris #famous dataset of flowers properties 
examples <- df[12:42,] # selection of examples. It could be arbitary though
```

Now,

```
new_df <- setdiff(df,examples)
```

If you want remove columns then just transpose the `dataframe` and examples after convert it to a matrix then apply `seetdiff()`

Let me know if this serves your purpose. If your issue is something other than above please let me know.